# Disable SEF/URL REWRITE for one Joomla menu

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

*(This is a very specific question - about Joomla)*

SEF is working fine and URLs are properly converted to search engine friendly URLs. But one link is not working `(http://<website>/news-update/gallery.html - <main-menu>->News and Update->Gallery)`. It is for JoomGallery component page.

Then I disabled the SEF options in Joomla and it works. After tired of trying to figure out the problem finally I decided to bypass Joomla's SEF processing just for this link (http:///index.php?option=com_joomgallery&view=favourites&layout=list). Is there an option in Joomla to do that? Or does anyone faced similar problem that some components don't work with SEF enabled?

Comment: This is probably an error with JoomGallery's router.php file. You need to ask the developer, not SO.

Comment: @mavrosxristoforos thanks! I removed the router.php file and the links started to work. I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so, since this question seems to have been answered in comments, I will also add the answer here:

This is probably an error with JoomGallery's router.php file.

Usually it is best to ask the developer about this, or check the router.php code if you have the experience to do so.

If you feel that removing the router.php file may not be the best way, you may want to post some code here.